# How to access the table,tr,td which has no attributes using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to access the table as well it rows and table data(td),generally the table,tr and td has no attributes to use I tried with index but still no use,even I tried with the parent element of table still I was unable to access it.

```
<div class = "Links"></div>
<div class = "board">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Value</td></tr>
<tr><td>shaik</td><td>500</td></tr>
<tr><td>shahrukh</td>900<td><span style="" has css properties ></span></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I tried in the following way

```
@ie.table(index,0) and 
@ie.div(:class,'Links').table(:index,0)
```

returned an error as unable to locate the element

[image: UI Screenshot]

Comment: Did you verify that the table is not in a `frame` or `iframe`? I recall some of your previous questions being caused by frames.

Comment: @ Justin Ko frames/iframes are not at all used.

Comment: I think you will need to provide more details on how to reproduce the problem. I created a page with the HTML you gave and `@ie.table(index,0)` worked as expected.

Comment: Even I tried with the same syntax as above,let me check once.......

Answer (score 1):

`@ie.table` by itself should work.
`@ie.div(:class, 'Links')` is not a parent of the table element since the `</div>` comes before the `<table>` in the dom.

Comment: irb(main):034:0> @ie.table(:index, 0)
=> #<Watir::Table:0x4edb24c located=false how=:index what=0> ,I got the above error when I tried with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
myelem = browser.tr(:text, /Name/).td(:index => 2).text
 #or you can use the more user-friendly aliases for those tags
myelem = browser.row(:text, /Name/).cell(:index => 2).text
```

Comment: irb(main):005:0> @ie.tr(:text,'name').td(:index,2).text
NoMethodError: undefined method `tr' for #<Watir::IE:0x4ef93a0>

Comment: irb(main):007:0> @ie.browser.tr(:text,'STORENO').td(:index,2).text
NoMethodError: undefined method `browser' for #<Watir::IE:0x4ef93a0>

Comment: irb(main):008:0> browser.tr(:text,'name').td(:index,2).text
NameError: undefined local variable or method `browser' for #<Object:0x3d9f99c>
        from (irb):8

Comment: That actually works on Watir::Browser class can you get that object from the Watir::IE class